# Drawing 2D measurements into PDF using iText

Tags: pdf, itext, measurement

Is there a way to draw a 2D measurement (a double sided arrow line with the measurement text) using iText? Simulating it by drawing a line and arrow heads is one way, but I am looking for a native 2D measurement API in iText.

Answer (score 0):

I had been searching for this for days and sad to say there looks to be no way to do this as I never found any article regarding this.

Yes, drawing it in PdfContentByte works. However, once you move the annotation, its painted drawing stays put, thus rendering this useless.

If the annotation is set to locked, then drawing it can work. But if it is movable or resizable, there needs to be an annotation to do this.

Comment: The OP does not mention a need to move the arrow around.